# Split file and filename from array of URL's into a new array?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `.map()` on an array of href's to extract the file and file name in the link location and place them into a new array.

The problem is how to convert the destructured array `const[file, folder]` into an array that will contain the file and folder for each of the URL's that the `linkContainer` variable contains, since `.map()` is iterating over it? It obviously it only collects the first one now.

URL examples would include:

- http://192.168.12.44:8090/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.pdf
- http://192.168.12.44:8090/INST_SHEET/R3CRN-trim_0.pdf

  ```
  const liveLinks = linkContainer.map(function(v, a){
  // v contains each URL
  const [file, folder] = v.split('/').reverse();
  if(document.location.hostname.indexOf('wacdev.waclighting.com') == 0) {
      urlResult[a] = v + 'http://192.168.12.44:8090'; // just for testing
        return urlResult;
  } else {
        urlResult[a] = v + 'https://waclighting-images.s3.amazonaws.com';
        return urlResult;
  }

  }); // Right now, file or folder only contains ONE file or folder name
  ```

Ideal output would be:

```
console.log(file, folder) // [SPECSHEET_PDF, INST_SHEET] [R3CRDT_SPSHT.PDF, R3CRN-trim_0.pdf] etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.slice()` to slice only the last two elements of the array.

```js
var url1 = "http://192.168.12.44:8090/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.pdf"

var url2 = "http://192.168.12.44:8090/INST_SHEET/R3CRN-trim_0.pdf"

const [file, folder] = url1.split("/").slice(-2);
const [file2, folder2] = url2.split("/").slice(-2);

const files = [file, file2];
const folders = [folder, folder2];

console.log(files, folders);
```

If the number of URLs could be anything:

```js
var urls = ["http://192.168.12.44:8090/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.pdf", "http://192.168.12.44:8090/INST_SHEET/R3CRN-trim_0.pdf"]

urls = urls.map(v => v.split("/").slice(-2))

//[file, file2], [folder, folder2] format
console.log(urls.map(v => v[0]), urls.map(v => v[1]));

//[file, folder] format
console.log(urls);
```

Comment: How can I automate it for a dynamic amount of HREFS? Say I have an var named `linkContainer` and it contains dynamic amount of links?

Comment: You can use `.map()`, although the output would be in `[file, folder]` format.